# Soap Service on JBOSS with Spring Boot Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss, spring-ws

when i deploy my WAR in JBOSS, my Spring BOOT with Spring WS have this error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/AttachmentPartImpl
how can i fix this?
I tried like that but without results
I created a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in webapp/WEB-INF where i wrote

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

in my pom i added:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

i read a similar topic here, and It say to do this:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"> 
  <property name="messageFactory">
     <bean class="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

I tried with,but without result.

```
@Bean
    public SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {
        SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
        SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl messageFactory1_1=new SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl();
        messageFactory.setMessageFactory(messageFactory1_1);
        return messageFactory;
    }
```

JBoss return me:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [PACKAGE.WebServiceConfig] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ARTIFACT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/ver1_1/SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl
```

but i'm using Spring Boot, how can i write this Bean in Spring Boot?

Thanks so much.

Comment: The XML is just another way of defining a bean. The fact that you use Spring Boot doesn't mean you cannot use XML anymore. And it directly translates to Java Code if you want (see https://mdeinum.github.io/2018-04-12-on-spring-applicationcontext-and-bean-creation/).

Comment: You can try adding saaj-impl.jar to jboss itself.

Comment: @Smile I cant touch the jboss :( :(

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried with the code that you can see now on the topic, but without result.

Comment: And the error you get is?

Comment: @M.Deinum The stack now is up, is a error in deploy now.

Comment: Try an older saaj version. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/ws/soap/saaj/SaajSoapMessageFactory.html

Comment: @M.Deinum  Nothing, same error, i tried with the 1.3.1.The error is up.

Comment: Which gives you another error. Remove the bean for the messagefactory and just include the older saaj version.